# Implement .NET Framework WCF service custom basic auth or custom token auth

Tags: c#, wcf, basic-authentication, .net-4.8, custom-authentication

For some reasons we must implement a **custom auth method** for a Net Framework 4.8 **WCF service**. It can be a custom basic or custom anything (for example token based) auth. The main goal is to publish a WCF service to IIS, but the clients need to use authentication (not anonymus) to access the service functions. During this authentication cannot use local users or AD users usernames and passwords. A virtual (fake) username + password pair should be the best.

Best solution would be not do develop anything, but an existing IIS authentication module is used (and configured). Unfortunately, our IIS server is still v6.2, and I cannot find any built-in auth modules to be configurable to authenticate the incoming request with an externally given static username + password pair. Like as an Apache .htpasswd file. Is there any?

I found examples on MS doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-a-module-using-net but it seems developed for ASP.NET, not for WCF. Cannot find example for WCF services. Can anyone suggest a working example (server side, client side) for this? Hopefully only on server side a development must be, because if this is a fully working basic auth, on client side the specific (fake) username + password must be stored and used during the calls.

```
context.AuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(this.AuthenticateUser);
```

Thanks for advance!

Comment: WCF is used for SOAP services. Unlike REST and JWT, SOAP is a well defined standard, with well defined authentication standards that are already supported by WCF. Don't try to roll your own, clients won't be able to use your services if you do. The supported interop standards are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/web-services-protocols-supported-by-system-provided-interoperability-bindings#wsfederationhttpbinding-and-ws2007federationhttpbinding). Tokens are used in federation scenarios, so you need the wsFederation bindings

Comment: [Federated and Issued Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/federation-and-issued-tokens) explains how to create services and clients that use the WS-Federation and WS-Trust specifications. Tokens are only needed when you *don't* want to send the credentials to the server though, only exchange a locally generated token.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to authenticate using custom user/password pairs, you just need basic authentication. ASP.NET always supported basic authentication with accounts stored eg in a database, through the Membership service. WCF works on top of ASP.NET so it can use the same Membership service

Comment: Chech [How To: Use the ASP.NET Membership provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-aspnet-membership-provider). It shows how to use ASP.NET's membership provider with WCF basic authentication.

Comment: You can check out [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96028/WCF-Service-with-custom-username-password-authenti).

Comment: Thanks all - I will check them! Thanks! Membership provider what I need not a custom auth module. I think.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if I use wsFederation and tokens - what Authentication method should I configure in IIS which hosts the WCF service?